# Find values of x where error term small between rounded and not calculation in non-linear functions f_{i}(x)

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-mathematics

Here's my situation. I have a set theory background so I'm out of my league in applied, computational methods so I'd appreciate a hand-up.

I have a set of five functions, $f_{i}(x) \ $ where $\ 0 < x < 1$. They are all of the form:
$$f_{i}(x) = \frac{a_{i}}{ b_{i}x + c_{i}}$$ where all a, b, c are constant and positive real numbers.

I also have a version of each function, call it $$f^{round}_{i} = \frac{a_{i}}{ round(b_{i}x) + c_{i}}$$ where the only difference is that bx is rounded in calculation.

Is there a numerical method to find ranges of values of x such that given $\epsilon > 0 \ \forall i <=5 \ \ |f^{round}_{i}(x) - f_{i}(x)| < \epsilon$?

Single values of x would also be fine.

Comment: What is $round(y)$ doing? Integer rounding, or something more close to fixed or floating point operations? Note that $f^{round}(x)=f(\tilde x)$ and $|f(\tilde x)-f(x)|\le\frac{ab|\tilde x-x|}{c^2}$.

Comment: round(y) is just an integer round.

Comment: Then you have to find $x$ where all $b_ix$ are nearly integer. The LLL algorithm could be your friend. (Lenstra-Lenstra-Lovacs).

Comment: @LutzL Thanks for the tip. I've looked into LLL, and I have a question. I was assuming that I'd be using LLL to find a polynomial approximation for $\Sigma_{i} |$round$(b_i x) - b_i x |$, then find roots, but that function has an extreme number of turning points in the domain. Is there an approach to use LLL to identify these nearly integers directly?